# Azure Custom Script extension - MSI install

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-bicep

I'm attempting to setup a simple CSE to install an MSI after my Bicep template creates a VM.
Both the PS script and MSI file are uploaded to a storage account container.

I have it working to the extent that the VM is created and I can see the PS script downloaded to the default CSE location on the VM i.e. C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Downloads\0\install.ps1

But its only the PS script that is downloaded - not the MSI file itself. So obviously the PS script which refers to the location of the MSI as .\ does not work as it is not in the same folder (or anywhere).

How do I get the MSI downloaded to the same folder location on the VM as the PS script?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out - didn't realise I had to add separate objects in the array for each file I wanted to download locally to the VM

settings: {
fileUris: [
installFileUri
msiUri
]